# How can I make environment variables available during Docker build for a Rails 7 app with MRSK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, mrsk

I'm trying to build and deploy a rails 7 app with MRSK. The docker build process needs different environment variables for bundling gems, installing yarn packages, etc.

My deploy.yml contains following information:

```yaml
env:
  secret:
    - GITLAB_TOKEN

builder:
  secrets:
    - GITLAB_TOKEN
  args:
    RUBY_VERSION: 3.2.2
  multiarch: false
```

The .env-file:

```
GITLAB_TOKEN='test'
```

In my Dockerfile I've tried following:

```
RUN echo  "$GITLAB_TOKEN"

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GITLAB_TOKEN
RUN cat /run/secrets/GITLAB_TOKEN
```

But the environment is in both cases empty.

---

I've found a workaround by using `args` instead of environments in the deploy.yml:

```yaml
builder:
  args:
    GITLAB_TOKEN: "<%= ENV['GITLAB_TOKEN'] %>"
```

But args are not masked secret and using erb-text in a yml-file seems very ugly. This also may not work for non rails-applications.

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that in your Dockerfile

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GITLAB_TOKEN \
  GITLAB_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/GITLAB_TOKEN) \
  bundle install # or any command you need
```